# 2005 Buick Rainier: Turn signals don't operate correctly and turn on the high lights instead

Tags: electrical, buick, turn-signal

When I operate the right directional, it does not work, instead the high lights come on. Occasionally the directional works.

The car is a 2005 Buick Rainier

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: 2005 buick rainier

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be a faulty turn signal switch. Diagnose the issue further by unplugging the switch checking the continuity on its terminals. A new aftermarket one costs about $100, plus labor, of course.